# Canny edge detector

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

I am coding my own version of Canny. So, from the literature we have to:

1. Smooth with gaussian

   - Here, i'm using a 5x5 mask
2. Compute gradient magnitude and orientation

   - Here, i'm using Sobel and then

     ```
     Grad = abs(Gx)+ abs(Gy)
     Orient = ( atan2(Gy/Gx) * 180/3.14159265 ) + 180
     ```
3. Non maximum suppression

   - For ex, if Orient = 0º => if G(i;j) > G(i;j-1) && G(i;j) > G(i;j+1) => MAX here, otherwise = 0
4. Double threshold

   - In this step, we get NL and NH
   - At this point, it is clear that NL contains NH, so NL = NL - NH
   - Now, for each non zero pixel p in NH(x,y) i have to mark as valid pixels all the weak pixels in NL(x,y) that are connected to p
5. Final image

   - It will be NL + NH

At the end I get the output from openCV Canny to compare.

What am i doing wrong ?

- [myCanny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61jFP.jpg)
- [openCVCanny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9RLP.jpg)

Comment: what is the output without step1?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV canny does not do any Gaussian filtering. Try not to filter it then compare the results.

P.S. I did not review all your steps. They may have another error/s

Answer (score 0):

Bloody hell! There was an error rounding the orientations to the possible four cases. I forgot to put the equal sign in some cases. Now it's all fixed.

Now i'm happy with the result :)

Thank you all!

Best regards